# Internal Server Error 500 in Mongod for Python code

Tags: python, mongodb, bottle

I am taking the MongoDB m101p course and I run into trouble;

- Started `mongod`
- Started `python blog.py` listener
- Logged in with a existing user
- Added a new post
- Added comments to that post

The problem is that every defined url works, not including the root url `localhost:8082/`
When I want to go on the landing page, I get `error: 500 internal server error`

Each time I modified the code, I restarted the python listener.
I can't validate the code, since the root url does not work

Any ideas?
the `/ route`:

```
# This route is the main page of the blog
@bottle.route('/')
def blog_index():

    cookie = bottle.request.get_cookie("session")

    username = sessions.get_username(cookie)

    # even if there is no logged in user, we can show the blog
    l = posts.get_posts(10)

    return bottle.template('blog_template', dict(myposts=l, username=username))
```

Comment: Turn on debugging. Bottle should have an option.

Comment: Pass `debug=True` to your bottle `run` function call as it's done [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#quickstart-hello-world).

Comment: Where are you defining `sessions` and `posts`? Seems like you're missing your `pymongo` connection call.

Comment: All the data is predifined by the 10gen guys. I have found the answer and my app is running now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you know that the code you wrote in python is the right code, seek for software answers.

You might need to restart the server in order to load the new code or in my case, delete the database;

I have palyed with the db on my own and not all the documents had the date set;

When the route `/` was called, because there was no `date` property in some of the documents, a error was generated.

Also, check for fields when you write code, bacause a field might be missing.

After I have deleted the db, created a new user, new posts, added comments, I validated the code and I got my answer.